# How to get value from a List of Items from View by using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a list View as:

```
@foreach(var item in model )
```

and it has some field as:

```
@html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>item.prodname ,new{@class="pn"})
```

I wanted to select a value of this prodname in jquery.

For this I have tried the following process but it doesn't give the required output.

```
$("#convt").click(function () {
    $.each(item, function () {
        var snm = (this,'.pn').val().trim();
    });
    alert(snm);
});
```

What correction do I need to select a value of this prodname in jquery?

Comment: `.val()` method return input value, to get text content of tag you must use `.text()` instead. can u make fiddle test for better answer?

Answer (score 0):

$(".class-name").text() should work, to get the text of element using class name.